# Why does my radio buttons goes to "Please Try Again" after I clicked on the right answer

Tags: android

I have a problem. After I created a question, it suddenly goes to please try again rather than the answer is correct. Can you please explain what the problem is?

```
submitbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(questionchoice1.isChecked() || questionchoice2.isChecked() || questionchoice3.isChecked()) {

                    if (questionchoice1.equals(quizAnswer)) {
                        mAnswer.setText("The answer is correct!");
                        mAnswer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    else if(questionchoice2.equals(quizAnswer))
                    {
                        mAnswer.setText("The answer is correct!");
                        mAnswer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    else if(questionchoice3.equals(quizAnswer))
                    {
                        mAnswer.setText("The answer is correct!");
                        mAnswer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    else if (!questionchoice1.equals(quizAnswer)){
                        mAnswer.setText("Please try again!");
                        mAnswer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    else if (!questionchoice2.equals(quizAnswer)){
                        mAnswer.setText("Please try again!");
                        mAnswer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    else if (!questionchoice3.equals(quizAnswer)){
                        mAnswer.setText("Please try again!");
                        mAnswer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    mAnswer.setText("Please select an answer");
                    mAnswer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: you can't compare radio button and string.

Comment: Answer and Question String must be diffrent , you should use Data object to compare  Answer of question with some mapping with given answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your questionchoice is a radio button and your quizAnswer is a variable of a different type (String, int, ...? I'm guessing String if you're using .equals()). So the method is not comparing the value of the radio button, but its reference. Please post your layout and the variable types you're using and I can update my answer with further info on how to solve your problem.

**UPDATE** after comment:

Get the value of the radio button that’s checked using:

```
 String quizChoice1 = questionchoice1.getText();
```

Then add the following to your check conditions:

```
if (quizChoice1.equals(quizAnswer)) { 
    //answer is correct
} else {
    //answer is wrong
}
```

Comment: Here is the code to convert from int to string: quizChoice1 = String.valueOf(questionchoice1.getId());
                quizChoice2 = String.valueOf(questionchoice2.getId());
                quizChoice3 = String.valueOf(questionchoice3.getId());

Comment: @ChuaTengSheng Not sure what the stucture of your code is, and if that would work, but if you're doing what you described above and you get the desired value, why don't you do if (quizChoice1.equals(quizAnswer)) { //answer is correct} else {//answer is wrong}

Answer (score 0):

"questionchoice1" is a radio button so you have to get the text of the Radio button first then compare that text to value in your variable "quizAnswer".

in java we can get text of radio button as

```
String value = questionchoice1.getText();
```

and in kotlin:

```
val value = questionchoice1.Text
```

then we can compare tat value to variable as

```
value.equal(quizAnswer)
```